# Схема MVC для браузерной игры

Tags: mvc, разработка-игр

Разобрался в схеме MVC, начал изучать Zend Framework, как тут и посоветовали.
Схема MVC действительно удобна для многих типов сайтов, на мой взгляд, но будет ли она удобной, для браузерной онлайн игры, какое ваше мнение?
Мне кажется, что там её будет сложнее/неудобнее применять.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да, умные мысли, спасибо)
А как насчёт того же Zend Framework для браузерки, нормально? Я ещё не ориентируюсь в фреймворках.

Comment: @Construct Да все `php` фреймворки приемлемы для этого. Лично я предпочитаю `Symfony`, на нем, например, сделана [**eRepublik.**][1]

[1]: http://www.erepublik.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Классический паттерн `MVC/MVP`, на мой личный взгляд, представляет собой неплохое решение и для браузерных игр. *Смотрите сами, есть некоторый набор моделей, который хранится на сервере, есть вид, который отрисовывается исключительно средствами браузера клиента, есть контроллер, который ответственен за изменения в модели.*

Модель - только на сервере, возможности для изменения данных собраны в одном месте, что упрощает борьбу со злоумышленниками. Состояние модели на сервере "проектируется" в браузер, и, например, если сама модель на сервере изменилась, то это изменение легко можно подцепить браузером клиента. *И так далее...*

По сути, если выбрать какой-либо стандартный фреймворк и воспользоваться известным механизмом синхронизации действий контроллера и соответствующей модели, то задача решена. Разумеется, на практике *(и в разработке браузерных игр)* все не так гладко, тем не менее тысячи проектов доказывают работоспособность и пользу от паттерна `MVC`.

---

**И потом, какие не-`MVC`-подобные альтернативы вообще можно предложить?**

В проектах такого типа любой отход от формализации *(утрированно)* *"данные - отрисованные данные - контролы для изменения данных"* уже автоматически начинает восприниматься как говнокод и у человека начинают спрашивать: *"А где Controller? Почему обработчики действий по изменению данных лежат в коде View?"* В клинических случаях в попытках изобрести велосипед можно дойти и до ***"Почему данные и вид не разделены? А если я по-другому хочу их отрисовать, что мне делать?"***

Если подытожить мое мнение, то *любое собственное решение будет так или иначе стремиться к `MVC`, в чем-то ему уступая.* В таком случае, очевидно, смысла изобретать что-либо самому нет.

---

> *Небольшой offtop:*  Для некоторых ситуаций, модель `MVP` подходит больше, чем `MVC`. Это, правда, не имеет прямого отношения к случаю `MMORPG` в браузере, но может быть полезно в ряде других ситуаций. Подробнее можно глянуть [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Завтра, на свежую голову, осмыслю глубже)

Comment: А почему вы предпочитаете Symfony?

Comment: @Construct Длинная история, скорее просто дело привычки. Поработал с `Code Igniter`, понравилось. Поработал с `Symfony` - понравилось еще больше, так и применяю для проектов. *Вообще, гуглите `php framework comparison`.*

Comment: А, да, действительно) спасибо.